# Force return to a given view when going to backkground

Tags: iphone

My application has an initial view asking a password and, when the password is valid, going to a view controller thru a segue.

When application is moving to the background, I would like to force a return to the initial view .

I guess that the corresponding code has to be inserted into app delagate applicationWillResignActive method but after a ton of attempts I can't find the appropriate code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your controllers are embedded in a navigation controller, and then simply use

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

if the target controller is the first one, or

```
popToViewController:animated:
```

if the target view controller is not the first one. Both methods are called on `self.navigationController`.

Comment: Thanks. In my current structure, the target window is not in a navigation controller but goes to a view controller thru a segue.

Comment: Just embed the first window in a navigation controller and every other window pushed on top of that one will be embedded as well.